# Securing logins done via Facebook connect

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, security

I'm testing Facebook connect right now. In pseudocode the approach is as follows:

```
if( isConnectedOnFacebook() ){

    user = getUserByFBID( fbId )

    if( user != none ){
        user.setConnected()
    } else {
        showLoginForm();
    }

} else {
    showLoginForm();
}
```

I'm kind of uneasy with the idea of equating an open FB account with a public "connect me without authentication" method. What are the potential flaws with this approach?

P.S: Using the PHP API.

Comment: I think the user has to grant your website permission to access their account first before they'll appear connected, won't they? Is that enough approval, or do you mean you want to protect against left-myself-logged-into-facebook abuse?

Comment: Yes, this works like a facebook application. I'm just wondering if there's a risk of reducing site security in having a public class method that logs in simply using a valid id. The case of "left-myself-logged-into-facebook" as you say should probably be considered too as a stranger would have access to everything the user has and could  trash their profile or create mishap among friends.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, if this is a public computer or shared within the family and the user stays logged in to Facebook, someone else could grant access to your app for them. The flip side is lowering barrier to entry to get your users connected and ready to go.

If your concern is how the login functionality works via the PHP SDK, it's not the UID that is used to authenticate.  This is done via an OAuth.  You can find out more about how OAuth works (and the PHP SDK under the covers) here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/